# X=[0,1], consider the measure space (X,$F$,m), if there is no point in infinitely many Borel sets $E_n$, show that $m(E_n)=0$ for some n.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let me express the problem in the counter way: Consider Lebesgue space ([0,1],$F(0,1)$,m), $E_n$ be Borel sets. If there exists $c$>0 s.t. $m(E_n) \geq c$ for all n, show that there exists at least one point that in infinite many sets $E_n$.

I try to use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma to find the n in tail term of a series, but is doesn't work. Could someone give me some help? Thanks.

Comment: Aren't the sets $E_n=(2^{n+1},2^n)$ Borel sets?

Comment: @Gaffney: Probably you mean $(2^{-(n+1)}, 2^{-n})$, or something similar? After all, we want subsets of $[0,1]$. Otherwise, it's a good example.

Comment: @PhoemueX That's what I meant.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gaffney I understand your example. thanks!

Comment: What is $F$? A $\sigma$-algebra generated by Borel sets? and what is $m$? is it some specific measure? or totally general?

Comment: @dEmigOd Sorry for the unclear . Here F is σ-algebra generated by Borel sets and m is lebesgue measure.

Comment: The statement in the title is not equivalent to the statement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Define $$A_k := \{x \in E_k : \forall n > k~~x \notin E_n\}$$

It is easy to see $A_k$ are disjoint and
$$\bigcup\limits_n E_n = \bigcup\limits_k A_k$$

From disjointness (and some work to see $A_k$ are measurable) you can conclude, that given $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find $N$, s.t.
$$m\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} A_k\right) < \varepsilon$$

but any $E_n \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} A_k$ for $n > N$.

contradiction to the fact $m(E_n) \geq c > 0$.

Comment: thanks! I am clear.